# What is the minimum number of gloves that should be picked to ensure that at I pick at least one pair of gloves of each colour?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

There is a drawer which contains 12 pairs of blue gloves, 12 pairs of grey and 12 pairs of black. What is the minimum number of gloves that should be picked to ensure that at I pick at least one pair of gloves of each colour

I chose $12$ right hand gloves of each colour - blue, grey and black. and then selected $3$ left hand gloves of each colour. Total=$39$.

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: If you can distinguish between left hand and right hand gloves while picking, then you can distinguish between colors as well, so why not just pick differently colored gloves immediately? The point is, you are assuming too much knowledge of what you are picking. You should assume that you know nothing of the glove until its already picked.

Comment: I have edited to refer to gloves throughout and not socks. In general in these kinds of questions socks come in one kind - two red socks make a pair, but gloves come in left- and right- handed versions. It is possible to assume that you can tell the difference between left-hand and right-hand gloves by touch.

Comment: @Mark Bennet, and what if I'm wearing a boxing glove while picking? This kind of non-mathematical assumptions should be stated explicitly, so appropriate model can be used. For example, I've never seen any combinatorial problem with gloves, considering that this is a GMAT question, wouldn't this question be unfairly disadvantageous to people like me?

Comment: @Ennar I agree the question is unclear. I edited it to clarify as far as possible, but one part said gloves and another said socks. So unclear is whether there are six kinds of things - twelve of each - of three kinds of things with twenty four of each. Also unclear is whether left and right can be distinguished. You will see in my answer that I have covered the possibilities. The wording of the question posted here is definitely not the precise wording of the GMAT paper, which may or may not have given the requisite detail.

Comment: @Mark, I do and it deserves an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can distinguish left and right by touch but not by sight, you can make sure you have a right-hand glove of each colour by pulling out $25$ gloves. Then pulling out a left-hand glove will make at least one pair. For a pair of each colour you need to pick out $25$ left-hand gloves to make sure that each colour is covered. Total $50$.

If you can't distinguish between left and right, you might pull out all the blue and grey gloves - a total of $48$ and then all the twelve black right-hand gloves before you pick (finally) a left-hand one to complete the final pair. Total $61$.

If we had socks instead, we might pick out all the blue and grey ones - total $48$ before picking any black ones. We need two black to make a pair, so $50$ are required.